# Pointer incremental issues

Tags: c++, pointers, increment

why does i get a warning message as expression result unused when using

```
*(p)++;
```

and do not recieve any warning here

```
int ans = *(p)++;
```

the value of `*p` passes the value into ans variable but it does not increment when printing.

Code:-

```
{
    int first = 10;
    int *p = &first;
    int **q = &p;
    int second = 20;
    *q = &second;
    int ans = *(p)++;
    *(p)++;
    cout<<first<<" "<<second;
    cout<<ans;
}
```

I was expecting it to increment. and used `++` sign in C++;

Comment: Could you please write a single line of Code on one line and specify where exactly you receive the warning

Comment: Does `*p++` resolve into `(*p)++` or `*(p++)`?

Comment: What do you think has higher priority, `*` or `++`?

Comment: Code should receive markup different to the one you originally posted. You can take a look at the changes I did to improve the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76982826/revisions

Comment: @Cristi in *(p)++; why my value of first which is 10 does not increment to 11.

Comment: @Jarod42 it resolves into (*p)++, i just want to know how exactly it is working in *(p)++ as it assigns the *p value but do not increment it??

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ++ maybe??

Comment: `*(p)++` is the same as `*p++`, which increments the variable `p`, i.e. the pointer, so it points to the next element (of which there are none).

Comment: `++` indeed has the higher priority (you don't need to guess, look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)), meaning you're contradicting yourself: it resoves to `*(p++)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  thanks a lot I think it is resolved now. it would be great help if you can resolve this question for me as well I cannot post any new questions today so i am gonna ask in comment section.
```
int main() {
  int first = 100;
  int *p = &first;
  int **q = &p;
  int second = ++(**q);
  int *r = *q;
  ++(*r);
  cout << first << " " << second;
} 
```
why does here ++(*r) does not increase the address value of p but increases the value stored in the address. i.e why answer is 101?

Comment: Thankyou for all the replies i was expecting 3-4 days before replies. Thanks for resolving it.

Comment: `*(p)++;` generates **warning: expression result unused** because the expression result is unused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postfix increment operator `++` has a higher precedence than the unary `*` operators so it is evaluated first, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

This means

```
*(p)++
```

is equivalent to

```
*(p++);
```

Note that this doesn't modify the value the pointer points to, but the pointer itself. This usually only makes sense in the context of an array. You'd need to add `()` brackets differently to achieve the desired effect:

```
int ans = (*p)++;
(*p)++
```

Comment: @AdrianMole whoopsie. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated that part of my answer. Effects are the same though.

Answer (score 1):

The statement expression `*(p)++` yields a result. You ignore that result, and let it go to waste. So if the compiler says that the result is unused then it's correct.

To increment the values you need to first dereference the pointer, and then use the increment operator: `(*p)++`.

---

And as mentioned in comments, `*(p)++` is really the same as `*p++` which gets the old result of `*p` and then increments the pointer.

Since you increment the pointer `p` once already, it will no longer point to a valid location. The second time you dereference the variable `p`, it will lead to *undefined behavior* as you're now out of bounds.

Comment: Does it really lead to UB, if you dereference the pointer, but don't actually access the value for reading or writing? Not 100% sure about this. (Note that the order of first 2 code snippets is reversed in the 3rd one).

Comment: @fabian Dereferencing an invalid pointer always lead to UB. By dereferencing the pointer, you read the value of where it's pointing. And if it's pointing out of bounds then it's an out-of-bounds read. That the result of that read is ignored doesn't matter.